# Pagination in PHP Codeigniter (the url is not working for next pages properly)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a gallery for images; What I'm trying to do is a simple pagination for showing images; in a way that in each page I show just 18 images!
So I tried the following code in my controller:

```
    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');
    $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images(18,  $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Gallery/index.php/gallery/index/';                
    $config['total_rows'] = count($this->Gallery_model->get_all_images());
    $config['per_page'] = 18;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['main_content'] = "gallery";
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

and in my Gallery_model I handled in a way that each time 18 images are shown based on uri->segment. In case if you need my Model methods:

```
public function get_images($per_page, $segment) {

    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path . "\output");
    $newFiles = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($newFiles as $file) {

        $images[] = array(
            'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'output/' . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'output/' . $file,
        );
    }

    $newImage = array();
    if ((($segment * $per_page)+$per_page) < count($images)) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $per_page; $i++) {

            $newImage[$i] = $images[($segment * $per_page) + $i];
        }
    }else
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($images)-($segment * $per_page); $i++) {

            $newImage[$i] = $images[($segment * $per_page) + $i];
        }
    }
    return $newImage;
}

    public function get_all_images() {
    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path . "\output");
    $newFiles = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));
    $images = array();
    foreach ($newFiles as $file) {

        $images[] = array(
            'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'output/' . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'output/' . $file,
        );
    }


    return $images;

}
```

Now everything is fine I have 25 images (more than 18 images) and I'm supposed to have two pages and I do have 2 pages, but the problem is when I click on the second page, the url goes to ..../index/18 instead of ..../index/1

What can be the problem?

I may not be clear, so please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Pagination is okay, it will go to `/index/18`, use this `uri->segment(3)` as `offset` in your query to fetch next set of results.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get what exactly you mean; could you please give more explanation Thanks :)

Comment: Pagination will work like this : first page : `/index` then second page : , `/index/18`, then third :  `/index/36` and so on. Now got what i meant to say?

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem I thought the url is supposed to pass 0,1,2,, and then I need to handle it like 1*18, 2*18,... I wish you had put your answer in a new message instead of comments so I had been able to mark it as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination is okay, it will go to /
index/18 , use this uri-

> segment(3) as offset in
>   your query to fetch next set of
>   results

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want the next page to index/2 then index/3 and so on instead of index/18. Codeigniter by default will add tot the url the start position for the next page meaning page will start from the record 18 in the database.

I think what you want is

> **$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;**
>   By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html